# Files in the trash keep reappearing in the trash after emptying

Tags: macos, trash

Using macOS 12.0.1 on a 2020 13" MBP M1, though this problem has existed since macOS Big Sur.

I have a number of video files in my trash which I deleted several weeks ago. It's about 100 files totaling about 81GB, and when I empty the trash they go away, but they reappear several days later. I haven't been able to work out exactly when they reappear, but it seems to be anywhere between a few days and a week or two. This is the fourth or fifth time these files have reappeared. As far as I can tell my trash directory isn't syncing with icloud or anything, so I'm not really sure how to solve this.

I suppose I could restore the files to their original location and `rm` from the terminal, but I'd rather solve the underlying issue than use a workaround.

Comment: Try restoring one. You can only restore if they were originally deleted from Finder … and, of course, if they're still in the correct .trash Trying it would be a diagnostic start point. If it does return properly, try Cmd/Opt/Backspace to delete without going to Trash.

Comment: @Tetsujin Most of the files were deleted from an application and so don't have the Put Back option, though a few do (which is surprising because they should also have  been deleted from the same source). But when I do Put Back on those, it says it can't because the directory doesn't exist anymore. Though I did pull one out to a different directory and delete it directly.

Comment: OK. I'd be tempted to repeat the successful action with the others & see how it goes.